# Most efficient way to find elements in jQuery

Tags: jquery, optimization

If I have a CSS class which I *only* ever apply to form elements, eg:

```
<form class="myForm">
```

Which of these two jQuery selectors is most efficient, and why?

```
a) $('form.myForm')

b) $('.myForm')
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As redsquare already mentioned, the selection algorithm changed in later jQuery versions (partly due to getElementsByClassName support). Additionally, I tested this with the most recent jQuery version to date (v1.6) and also added a test for document.getElementsByClassName for comparison (works at least in Firefox 4 and Chrome).

The results in Firefox 4 were:

```
// With 100 non-form elements:
$('.myForm') : 366ms
$('form.myForm') : 766ms
document.getElementsByClassName('myForm') : 11ms

// Without any other elements:
$('.myForm') : 365ms
$('form.myForm') : 583ms
document.getElementsByClassName('myForm') : 11ms
```

The accepted answer is outdated (and is still found by searching for something like "efficient way to find elements in jquery") and can mislead people, so I felt that I have to write this.

Also, take a look at the time difference between jQuery and native browser selector functions. In jQuery 1.2.6 `$('.myForm')` was more than **300** times slower than `getElementsByClassName`, while in jQuery 1.6 it was *only* about **20** times slower, but still faster than `$('form.myForm')` (contrary to the outdated answer).

**Note:** The results were obtained with Firefox 4 (similar results with Chrome). In Opera 10 querying with tag name is only slightly faster, but Opera also supports the much faster native `getElementsByClassName`.

**Test code:** http://jsbin.com/ijeku5

Answer (score 22):

> **Edit**: The results below are for jQuery 1.2.6, probably in Firefox 3.5. Speed improvements in browsers and jQuery itself have pretty much rendered this information obsolete.

---

I just wrote a quick benchmarking test:

- On a page with 4 forms and about 100 other elements:

  - Using `$('form.myForm')` 10000 times took 1.367s
  - Using `$('.myForm')` 10000 times took 4.202s  (**307%**)
- On a page with only 4 forms and no other elements:

  - Using `$('form.myForm')` 10000 times took 1.352s
  - Using `$('.myForm')` 10000 times took 1.443s (**106%**)

It appears that searching for elements of a particular name is much quicker than searching all elements for a particular class.

**Edit:** Here's my test program: http://jsbin.com/ogece

The program starts with 100 `<p>` tags and 4 `<form>`s, runs the two different tests, removes the `<p>` tags and runs the test again. Strangely, when using this technique, **form.myForm is slower**. Take a look at the code for yourself and make of it what you will.

Comment: maybe provide the test cases on pastebin.me or jsbin.com nickf?

Comment: Possibly also dependent on the browser and which CSS selectors are natively supported.

Answer (score 7):

The first selector should be faster because jQuery can use the built-in function "getElementsByTagName" to reduce the number of elements it needs to filter. The second one has to get all the elements in the DOM and check their class.

Answer (score 4):

Try [slickspeed](http://mootools.net/slickspeed/) where you can see the rough speeds of selectors across a multiple of js libs including jquery.

Comment: cool site! jQuery wins! though, it doesn't test .className vs tagName.className :(

Answer (score 1):

form.myForm IMO is much quicker as it only needs to be look at a subset/filtered set of elements and would not need to iterate the whole document.

Answer (score 1):

The first example goes a LOT faster when used with a context.  The second example goes faster as well, but not by much.  I expanded your example to compare with a context:

http://jsbin.com/uluwe

Answer (score 0):

enobrev, Interesting.
I just ran your example but using jquery 1.3 beta 2 [here](http://jsbin.com/eruwa)

results.... (1.2.6 speed in brackets)

```
// With 100 non-form elements and Context:
$('.myForm', '#someContainer') : 4063ms (3707ms)
$('form.myForm', '#someContainer') : 6045ms (4644ms)

// With 100 non-form elements: 
$('.myForm') : 3954ms (25086ms)
$('form.myForm') : 8802ms (4057ms)

// Without any other elements with Context: 
$('.myForm', '#someContainer') : 4137ms (3594ms)
$('form.myForm', '#someContainer') : 6627ms (4341ms)

// Without any other elements: 
$('.myForm') : 4278ms (7303ms) 
$('form.myForm') : 8353ms (4033ms)
```

Comment: Woah, forget the context for 1.3!!  Also, that's a pretty big difference for the 2nd test (between versions).  Looks like jquery lost a bit of speed for form.myForm, but the huge gain for .myForm will likely make a bigger difference overall.

Answer (score -6):

C'mon guys? Are you crazy? The most *speedy* way to select an element is the shortest way:

$('.myForm') is way faster than $('form.myform') because the second variant hast to do aditional check to make sure that the element has the specified tagName. MAYBE the new jquery 1.3 will change this thing, but on latest stable version, is wrong to specify the tagName too. You should [read here](http://dev.iamntz.com/78/which-selector-is-faster).

I think i read somewhere that MooTools is way faster this way. Well.. Maybe in Moo, don't know, but in jQuery this is the fastest way.

take a look at this profiler:
[image]

([big pic](http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1112/3173092303_319d20dcb8_o.png))

first is only with ID, second is with form#ID (tested on my blog page) and work exactly same for class selector.

Comment: searching for elements by tag name is faster than searching for elements by class name. form.myForm means you only need to search through a smaller subset of the elements. If you only have a couple of elements, then you're doing two searches and it might be slower, but in real life form.myForm wins.

Comment: take a look at profiler results (or do your own tests) then tell me this. Also, even John Resig confirmed this ;)

Comment: also, the test is made on real life, not on a test site. you can try even here, on SO to be sure i'm telling the truth :)

Comment: but your using an id selector so of course if you rpefix with tagName it is slower as the lib cannot use getElementById!!!

Comment: check and change your test to use the .class selector. you will see the difference

Comment: I can't believe that the most complete reply got negative rating and the most WRONG got TWO positive rating.

 Anyhow, would be nice if i got some arguments for that down vote...

Comment: just read the posts below and go to the link discussed to see .class IS slower than element.class http://jsbin.com/uluwe