# How to get the radiobutton for corresponding datalisty item?

Tags: asp.net

I want to convert this code to JavaScript code:

```
rdb1 = (RadioButton)DataList1.Items[i].FindControl("rdb1");
```

How can it be done?

Comment: are you just trying to get the radio who's id is rdb1?

Comment: yea,rdb1 is the id of radiobutton,,i want to get that corresponding radiobutton of datalist item

Answer (score 0):

Put a unique class on the radio button and then you can easily use jQuery to walk the DOM and find that control.

Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415629/most-efficient-way-to-find-elements-in-jquery) of finding a control here on Stack Overflow.

Here is a [tutorial](http://www.learningjquery.com/2006/12/how-to-get-anything-you-want-part-2) of How to Get Anything You Want from a web page via jQuery.

Good luck, and hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript using the **id** attribute makes it easy to retreive a specific element since the id must be **unique** for `all tags`.

```
var radio1= document.getElementById("rdb1"); //this returns the element
```

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.getElementById) is a simple tutorial on how to do other things after getting the element.

**EDIT-** I see you just want the selected value in javascript:

```
function radiochanged(){
 var radio1= document.getElementById("rdb1");
 var rdb1_value;
 for (i=0;i<radio1.length;i++) 
 { 
    if (radio1[i].checked) 
   { 
         rdb1_value = radio1[i].value; 
   } 
  } 
}

<input id="rdb1" type="radio" onClick="radiochanged()">
```